# Android messed up R.java unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff

Tags: java, android

I accidentally set the id of a button to "mybutton-1" in my layout xml. When I hit "Run App" in Android Studio, it switched to R.java with an error at

`public static final int mybutton-1=0x7f0b00e1;`
and the error message said that there is a `;` expected after the -1. So I changed the id of that button in the layout xml to "myButton_a" and hit run app again. This time I got an error in my mainActivity.java at:

```
ArrayList<View> focusableViews = view.getFocusables(View.FOCUS_FORWARD);
for (int i = 0; i < focusableViews.size(); i++) {
     View actualView = focusableViews.get(i);
     String actualID = actualView.getResources().getResourceEntryName(actualView.getId()); // here
     ...
}
```

I looked at R.java and it updated my changes as expected to
`public static final int myButton_a=0x7f0b00e1;`

Here is the stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: myApp.mainActivity, PID: 31364
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myApp.mainActivity/myApp.mainActivity.mainLayout}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceEntryName(Resources.java:3738)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getResourceEntryName(ResourcesWrapper.java:264)
                      at myApp.mainActivity.doStuff(mainActivity.java:341)
                      at myApp.mainActivity.onCreate(mainActivity.java:71)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

How can I solve this problem? I read that I have to set the ID manually but is there another way? I dont want to mess with the IDs any more

Comment: What does `actualView.getId()` outputs?

Comment: Error says the value of `actualView.getId()` is `0xffffffff`. So one of your ids is -1.

Comment: clean your project and rebuild it

Comment: actualView.getId() was indeed -1 because I had a focusable View without an ID.
cleaning and rebuilding the project was a good shot but it didn't work. 
I had to add IDs to some focusable views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view doesn't have a id, then `getId()` will return -1. So it comes to be 0xffffffff.

It seems that your `focusableViews` not only contain mybutton1, **but also some others with no id**. That's the problem.